# pg8000 creating a table confuses column name with type

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, pg8000

I am using pg8000 for Postgres api in my python package.  I created a function that is to create a table is no such table exists.  The function is below:

```
    def create_tables(self, cur, tables):

       for i, table in enumerate(tables):
            name = 'important_' + table
            query = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} (
                        {}  CHAR(9),
                        {}  DATE,
                        {}  DECIMAL,
                        {}  TIME,
                        {}  TIME,
                        {}  NUMERIC,
                        {}  CHAR,
                        {}  CHAR,
                        {}  DECIMAL 
                    )
                '''.format(name, "key", "date", "cycle_sequence", "sent_time","processed_time", "amount", "sender", "receiver", "jumbo")

            cur.execute(query)
```

The query runs without error (in program and an online fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/38227)) except that the table column names are for example: "key CHAR(9)", "date DATE", etc.  So the query is executing but not recognizing the syntax.  But the query syntax is correct according to [this](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-create-table/). Any tips?

NOTE 1:  There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355630/python-mysql-error-in-query) but I do not have similar symptoms because I do not get a syntax error.  My query is successful.

Comment: Unrelated, but: [don't use the `char` type](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Comment: The usual way to deal with things like that: print the generated statement and run it manually (e.g. in `psql`) . Then **[edit]** your question and add the error message you get.

Comment: I edited the question to expand on 'worked fine'.

Comment: "*not recognizing the syntax*" would mean it doesn't run. If it runs successfully, it **does** recognize the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems odd to me but the 'fix' was to remove the space before the '(' in the column specification portion of the query as below.  With the space the (name, type) tuples are interpreted as a single string, without the space they are correctly interpreted as column name and type.

```
query = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} (...

query = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}(...
```

For the record I'm using: PyCharm 2019.2.3 (Community Edition) with Anaconda 1.9.7.  The db api is the 'pg8000' package.